# Trigger a click in Ionic on a date input

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, datepicker

Im currently working on an app using Ionic v1 (and therefor AngularJS). I show a simple button in a form that when clicked will open the native datepicker. I know that `<input type="date">` will trigger the native datepicker for Android or IOS. So what im trying to make is an inputfield that is hidden and a button that will call a function to trigger a click.

However, things like:
`angular.element(document.querySelector(elementClassName)).triggerHandler('click');`

Or

`angular.element('#elementIdName').triggerHandler('click');`

dont seem to work, or at least wont focus and trigger the datepicker Also i found that making the input focused (using a simple directive) does focus the input but doesnt trigger the native modal. (also the inputfield is not hidden at the moment so that cant be the issue either). The code for this below:

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Date</label>
    <input type="date" id="invoice-date" ng-model="invoice.datum" ng-blur="changeDateDialog()" show-focus="changeDate">
</md-input-container>

<md-button class="md-raised _58 _align-right" ng-click="changeDateDialog()">
    {{ invoice.datum | date }}
</md-button>
```

and the function:

```
$scope.changeDateDialog = function() {
    if($scope.changeDate ===  false) {
      $scope.changeDate = true;
    } else {
      $scope.changeDate = false;
    }`
```

I've look around for quite a while but nothing seems to work so far. Can anybody tell me something about the native datepicker and how to trigger it. All advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

if you have jquery added

`$('#elementIdName').focus()`

Or

`angular.element(document.)`

Comment: I've already tried `angular.element` and then focussing. The focus works when using a directive but it doesnt trigger the native datepicker on mobile. JQuery is not an option since Ionic works with AngularJs so i only have exces to JQLite. Thanks anyway